# How to make part of pattern required if specific character is present

Tags: regex, validation, pattern-matching

Actually i have this pattern:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.)?[0-9]{1,3},*?[0-9]{0,2}$
```

that do what I need, allow users to type: 1.234,56 / 1234,56 / 123,56 / 1 but the problem is that it allows 1.000 (thousand with dot separator - I don't need this), is there a way to make the comma required IF at least one dot is present?

Please no javascript solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex is anchored at the beginning (e.g. by `^`) you can use a positive lookahead for a string which either contains a `.` *and* a `,`, or doesn't contain a `.`, and then match your existing pattern:

```
(?=.*\..*,|[^.]+$)([0-9]{1,3}?\.?)??([0-9]{1,3})(,[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/03rJET/6)

Comment: As a helpful answer, you got my upvote. Nice with the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your pattern `,*?[0-9]{0,2}` matches 0+ times a comma followed by 0-2 digits which would for example make the total match valid for  `1.1,,,`.

What you could also do it use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either the variant that contains a dot and a comma or `|` match one or more digits followed by an optional part that matches a comma and 1-2 digits.

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{2})?)$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/biRIoe/1)

Explanation

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,2}` Make the comma required when there is a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{2})?` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional comma and 1-2 digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

Comment: This covers all the bases.